# Making an HttpRequest with MultipartEntity in it

Tags: java, apache, multipartentity

I've been frustrated at trying to figure out how to make an http request with a multipart entity in it. The multipart has a custom boundary but I can't seem to be able to set it. My code below results in a response message of saying that my message does not contain multiple parts.

```
HttpPut addDoc = new HttpPut(url);
addDoc.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=\"END_OF_PART\"");
String bodyString = "Test for multipart update";
String titleString = "Title Test for multipart update";
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
StringBody title = new StringBody(titleString, "application/atom+xml",Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
StringBody body = new StringBody(bodyString, "text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
entity.addPart("title", title);
entity.addPart("body", body);
addDoc.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to remove addHeader part from your code and change your constructor to

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,null,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try using:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
```

which is the correct way to initialize it, and then:

```
addDoc.setEntity(entity.build());
```

as for the boundary your question is not clear whether you need to read a custom boundary or set it, anyway the custom boundary is set in the following way;

```
multipartEntity.setBoundary("some-mimetype-boundary-unique-string");
```